# Unable to reload kendo grid after update or remove

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have kendo grid I can update or remove row on it. But the problem is I cannot refresh kendo grid immediately after update or remove row , but when hit f5 to reload it works well. I tried many ways it does not work.

```
    $.post(LogstimeEditConstants.urlLogstimeEditRead, { projectId: projectid,  userId: userid },
            function (result) {
                objdata = eval(result.data);
                defaultProjectId = result.defaultProjectId;
            });
        var dslogstime = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: objdata,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        Id: { required: true },
                        ProjectID: { defaultValue: defaultProjectId },
                        WorkDate: { type: "date", defaultValue: dateselect },
                        TaskId: { defaultValue: defaultTaskId },
                        WorkHours: { type: "number", defaultValue: "0.5" },
                        Description: {},
                        IsDelete: { type: "boolean", defaultValue: false }
                    }
                }
            },
            sort: [{ field: "ProjectID", dir: "asc" }]
        });
        timelogGrid = $("#tleditgrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dslogstime,
            scrollable: true,
            editable: "inline",
    });

$("#savebutton").click(function (e){
// Remove Logstime
        $.ajaxSetup({ async: false });
        for (var i = 0; i < deleteTimeLogsData.length; i++) {
            if (deleteTimeLogsData[i].IsDelete === true) {
                var timelogsId = deleteTimeLogsData[i].Id;
                $.post(LogstimeEditConstants.urlLogstimeDelete, { logstimeId: timelogsId },
                    function (result) {
                            $.post(LogstimeEditConstants.urlLogstimeEditRead, { editType: edittype, projectId: projectid, selectDay: selectday, selectMonth: selectmonth, userId: userid },
                            function (result) {
                                objdata = eval(result.data);
                                defaultProjectId = result.defaultProjectId;
                            });
                            timelogGrid.dataSource.read();
                            timelogGrid.refresh();
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
});
```

Please help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try on the $.post(LogstimeEditConstants,...
to reassign timelogGrid.dataSource.data = objdata;
before refreshing.
That means you have to put the next two lines inside the response

timelogGrid.dataSource.read();                            timelogGrid.refresh();